# JBOSS BPM Suite Installer Error: No 'jar' binary detected in PATH. Please make sure this binary exists before continuing the installation

Tags: java, jboss, drools, redhat, jbpm

[image]

I am trying to install JBOSS BPM Suite but get this error. I have looked around the web for a solution but did not find anything that really explains how to resolve this. I have JBOSS EAP 7 installed but have no idea how to set the 'jar' binary in PATH.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is *install the JDK* and *include the `bin` folder of JDK in your `Path` system variable*.

See: [No ‘jar’ binary detected in PATH](http://big.info/2017/01/redhat-jboss-bpm-suite-installation-error-no-jar-binary-detected-in-path.html)

Answer (score 0):

Run it from the bin folder of JDK.
e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin>java -Dizpack.mode=privileged -jar D:\BPM\jboss-bpmsuite-installer-6.2.0.BZ-1299002.jar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  My issue was resolved by adding the additional java components on top of the included openjdk in RHEL:
yum install java-devel